# rSpec ==/eql can't compare the 'same' things

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, rspec-rails

I have a controller index test that gets an ActiveRecord scope.
The test currently looks like this (including some inline debugging stuff):

```
describe "GET index" do
  it "assigns all schools as @schools" do
    get :index
    puts assigns(:schools).class
    puts School.populated.class
    assigns(:schools).should == School.populated
  end
end
```

The output is this:

```
ActiveRecord::Relation
ActiveRecord::Relation

expected: []
     got: [] (using ==)
Diff:
```

This is definitely not the first time I've had this in recent versions of Rails and rSpec.
Previously a coworker would just wrap the items in a `to_a` to compare them, which I find a bit dirty and likely not a good solution.

Any ideas? I'm curious as to why it thinks they are different, and how this same test passed in older versions of Rails and/or rSpec.

Comment: do you want to verify the class or object population? Relation provides Lazy Load, so you do not have any executed query on the step

Comment: Ah yes, I see, so using something like `.all` or `.to_a` would invoke the query?

Comment: yes, Lazy Load means the fire the query on first request

Comment: If you could turn that into an answer I'd gladly accept it!  :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**eql** is the same as **==**. Author of Rspec talks only do not use **!=**, use **should_not** instead

```
actual.should == expected
#is interpreted as this:

actual.should.==(expected)

#This is not true for !=. Ruby interprets this: actual.should != expected
#as follows:

!(actual.should.==(expected))
```

**Update**: Relation provides Lazy Load pattern, so you do not have any executed query on the step. It means the fire the query on first request

Comment: I this case I'm not mocking or stubbing like I normally do, I'm just testing that the controller fetches the right stuff from the model.

I'm just curious as to why it thinks they are different, and how this same test passed in older versions of Rails and/or rSpec.

Comment: Actually with the current RSpec + Rails + Ruby version eql is NOT the same as == for ActiveRecord queries. Where comparing with eql returns false for me for the same models == returns with true. I think eql fails because the 'created_at' and 'updated_at' times are slightly different somehow - I suppose it's a type mismatch (double vs int): 2012-07-06 16:09:41 vs 2012-07-06 16:09:41.760623

Answer (score 1):

If you want to compare arrays, you should write

```
 assigns(:schools).all.should =~ School.populated.all
```

Comment: If the relation gets evaluated, you get an array.